# MIME Type for uploaded files on S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, mime-types

How can I change mime type for uploaded files on Amazon S3. I have tried with http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/change_content_type but its not working.

Comment: what is the error/message you get?

Comment: isOK is displaying true, but not working in real.

Comment: // Instantiate the class
  $s3 = new AmazonS3();
 
  $response = $s3->change_content_type('my-bucket', 'test1.txt', 'text/plain');
 
  // Success?
  var_dump($response->isOK());

Comment: you would need to post the code that's not working, the AS3 function 'change_content_type' is returning true. Something else must not be working

Comment: I am working with sample code so there is no noticeable change in code.

Comment: Any way to debug ... and check where is the problem ....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try this:

```
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$bucket_name = 'my-bucket';
$file_name   = 'test1.txt';
$mime_type   = getMimeType($file_name);

$response = $s3->change_content_type($bucket_name, $file_name, $mime_type);

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());

function getMimeType($file) {
    // MIME types array
    $mimeTypes = array(
        "323"       => "text/h323",
        "acx"       => "application/internet-property-stream",
        "ai"        => "application/postscript",
        "aif"       => "audio/x-aiff",
        "aifc"      => "audio/x-aiff",
        "aiff"      => "audio/x-aiff",
        "asf"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
        "asr"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
        "asx"       => "video/x-ms-asf",
        "au"        => "audio/basic",
        "avi"       => "video/x-msvideo",
        "axs"       => "application/olescript",
        "bas"       => "text/plain",
        "bcpio"     => "application/x-bcpio",
        "bin"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "bmp"       => "image/bmp",
        "c"         => "text/plain",
        "cat"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkiseccat",
        "cdf"       => "application/x-cdf",
        "cer"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
        "class"     => "application/octet-stream",
        "clp"       => "application/x-msclip",
        "cmx"       => "image/x-cmx",
        "cod"       => "image/cis-cod",
        "cpio"      => "application/x-cpio",
        "crd"       => "application/x-mscardfile",
        "crl"       => "application/pkix-crl",
        "crt"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
        "csh"       => "application/x-csh",
        "css"       => "text/css",
        "dcr"       => "application/x-director",
        "der"       => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
        "dir"       => "application/x-director",
        "dll"       => "application/x-msdownload",
        "dms"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "doc"       => "application/msword",
        "dot"       => "application/msword",
        "dvi"       => "application/x-dvi",
        "dxr"       => "application/x-director",
        "eps"       => "application/postscript",
        "etx"       => "text/x-setext",
        "evy"       => "application/envoy",
        "exe"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "fif"       => "application/fractals",
        "flr"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "gif"       => "image/gif",
        "gtar"      => "application/x-gtar",
        "gz"        => "application/x-gzip",
        "h"         => "text/plain",
        "hdf"       => "application/x-hdf",
        "hlp"       => "application/winhlp",
        "hqx"       => "application/mac-binhex40",
        "hta"       => "application/hta",
        "htc"       => "text/x-component",
        "htm"       => "text/html",
        "html"      => "text/html",
        "htt"       => "text/webviewhtml",
        "ico"       => "image/x-icon",
        "ief"       => "image/ief",
        "iii"       => "application/x-iphone",
        "ins"       => "application/x-internet-signup",
        "isp"       => "application/x-internet-signup",
        "jfif"      => "image/pipeg",
        "jpe"       => "image/jpeg",
        "jpeg"      => "image/jpeg",
        "jpg"       => "image/jpeg",
        "js"        => "application/x-javascript",
        "latex"     => "application/x-latex",
        "lha"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "lsf"       => "video/x-la-asf",
        "lsx"       => "video/x-la-asf",
        "lzh"       => "application/octet-stream",
        "m13"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
        "m14"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
        "m3u"       => "audio/x-mpegurl",
        "man"       => "application/x-troff-man",
        "mdb"       => "application/x-msaccess",
        "me"        => "application/x-troff-me",
        "mht"       => "message/rfc822",
        "mhtml"     => "message/rfc822",
        "mid"       => "audio/mid",
        "mny"       => "application/x-msmoney",
        "mov"       => "video/quicktime",
        "movie"     => "video/x-sgi-movie",
        "mp2"       => "video/mpeg",
        "mp3"       => "audio/mpeg",
        "mpa"       => "video/mpeg",
        "mpe"       => "video/mpeg",
        "mpeg"      => "video/mpeg",
        "mpg"       => "video/mpeg",
        "mpp"       => "application/vnd.ms-project",
        "mpv2"      => "video/mpeg",
        "ms"        => "application/x-troff-ms",
        "mvb"       => "application/x-msmediaview",
        "nws"       => "message/rfc822",
        "oda"       => "application/oda",
        "p10"       => "application/pkcs10",
        "p12"       => "application/x-pkcs12",
        "p7b"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
        "p7c"       => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
        "p7m"       => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
        "p7r"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp",
        "p7s"       => "application/x-pkcs7-signature",
        "pbm"       => "image/x-portable-bitmap",
        "pdf"       => "application/pdf",
        "pfx"       => "application/x-pkcs12",
        "pgm"       => "image/x-portable-graymap",
        "pko"       => "application/ynd.ms-pkipko",
        "pma"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pmc"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pml"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pmr"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pmw"       => "application/x-perfmon",
        "pnm"       => "image/x-portable-anymap",
        "pot"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "ppm"       => "image/x-portable-pixmap",
        "pps"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "ppt"       => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "prf"       => "application/pics-rules",
        "ps"        => "application/postscript",
        "pub"       => "application/x-mspublisher",
        "qt"        => "video/quicktime",
        "ra"        => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
        "ram"       => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
        "ras"       => "image/x-cmu-raster",
        "rgb"       => "image/x-rgb",
        "rmi"       => "audio/mid",
        "roff"      => "application/x-troff",
        "rtf"       => "application/rtf",
        "rtx"       => "text/richtext",
        "scd"       => "application/x-msschedule",
        "sct"       => "text/scriptlet",
        "setpay"    => "application/set-payment-initiation",
        "setreg"    => "application/set-registration-initiation",
        "sh"        => "application/x-sh",
        "shar"      => "application/x-shar",
        "sit"       => "application/x-stuffit",
        "snd"       => "audio/basic",
        "spc"       => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
        "spl"       => "application/futuresplash",
        "src"       => "application/x-wais-source",
        "sst"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkicertstore",
        "stl"       => "application/vnd.ms-pkistl",
        "stm"       => "text/html",
        "svg"       => "image/svg+xml",
        "sv4cpio"   => "application/x-sv4cpio",
        "sv4crc"    => "application/x-sv4crc",
        "t"         => "application/x-troff",
        "tar"       => "application/x-tar",
        "tcl"       => "application/x-tcl",
        "tex"       => "application/x-tex",
        "texi"      => "application/x-texinfo",
        "texinfo"   => "application/x-texinfo",
        "tgz"       => "application/x-compressed",
        "tif"       => "image/tiff",
        "tiff"      => "image/tiff",
        "tr"        => "application/x-troff",
        "trm"       => "application/x-msterminal",
        "tsv"       => "text/tab-separated-values",
        "txt"       => "text/plain",
        "uls"       => "text/iuls",
        "ustar"     => "application/x-ustar",
        "vcf"       => "text/x-vcard",
        "vrml"      => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "wav"       => "audio/x-wav",
        "wcm"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "wdb"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "wks"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "wmf"       => "application/x-msmetafile",
        "wps"       => "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "wri"       => "application/x-mswrite",
        "wrl"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "wrz"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "xaf"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "xbm"       => "image/x-xbitmap",
        "xla"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlc"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlm"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xls"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlsx"      => "vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlt"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xlw"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "xof"       => "x-world/x-vrml",
        "xpm"       => "image/x-xpixmap",
        "xwd"       => "image/x-xwindowdump",
        "z"         => "application/x-compress",
        "zip"       => "application/zip"
    );

    $extension = end(explode('.', $file));
    return $mimeTypes[$extension]; // return the array value
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as its helpful, but "change_content_type" is not working for me.

Comment: really? "png" is missing?
"Only variables should be passed by reference ..." in end()...


use instead:

    $e = explode('.', $file);
    $extension = end($e);

Comment: "png" => "image/png"  missed

Comment: Also missing :
            "woff"      => "font/woff",
            "woff2"     => "font/woff2",
            "eot"       => "application/vnd.ms-fontobject",
            "ttf"       => "font/ttf",

Comment: also missing vtt and srt file types, if any one know please add that also

Answer (score 2):

The core Amazon S3 service makes no attempt to preserve the ACLs or content-types during a copy-in-place (i.e., replace) operation.

I know that the AmazonS3::change_content_type() method is simply a wrapper around the copy_object() method. If you [look at the implementation](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/blob/master/services/s3.class.php#L2209), you'll see that the PHP SDK makes an attempt to lookup the current ACL and content-type before executing the copy-in-place operation to workaround this problem in the core S3 service.

If it isn't working for you, have you posted this as a bug to the [AWS PHP forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=80)? It appears that the developer of the SDK is pretty responsive to addressing bugs that get reported there.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are facing a similar problem and want to solve it by the aws-cli then here is the solution:

```
aws s3 cp <src> <dest> metadata-directive REPLACE --content-type image/jpeg --acl public-read
```

Here is the **[official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)**: "If REPLACE is used, the copied object will only have the metadata values that were specified by the CLI command. Note that if you are using any of the following parameters: --content-type, content-language, --content-encoding, --content-disposition, --cache-control, or --expires, you will need to specify --metadata-directive REPLACE for non-multipart copies if you want the copied objects to have the specified metadata values."