# Find Mime type of file or url using php for all file format

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, mime-types, content-type, cdn

Hi I am looking for best way to find out mime type in php for any local file or url.
I have tried [mime_content_type][1] function of php but since it is deprecated I am looking for better solution in php for all file format.

```
mime_content_type — Detect MIME Content-type for a file ***(deprecated)***
```

I have already tried below function

```
echo 'welcome';
if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
    echo 'testing';
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, "http://4images.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Siberian-Tiger-Running-Through-Snow-Tom-Brakefield-Getty-Images-200353826-001.jpg");
    finfo_close($finfo);
    echo $mimetype;
}
```

Above code is not working for me, I am only seeing `welcome` for output.I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here.

---

Below code works somehow in my local but it does not work for urls.

```
$file = './apache_pb2.png';
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);  // object oriented approach!
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));  // e.g. gives "image/jpeg"
$mime  = explode(';', $mime_type);
print $mime[0];
```

Is there some work around which work for both(url and local).what is the best practice to set mime type for all contents (image, video, file etc.) other than mime_content_type function in php.also is it recommended to use the mime_content_type function in php, Is it best practice in php ?
[1]: https://www.php.net/mime_content_type

Comment: FYI `mime_content_type()` is not deprecated. It was at some point accidentally marked as deprecated in the online manual but this has since been corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer,

To find the extension of the file best way is to use [path_info](http://www.development-cycle.com/2012/08/php-file-extensions-pathinfo/) for both local files and url.

```
$info     = pathinfo($filename);

$basename = $info['basename'];

$ext      = $info['extension'];
```

create an array for the mime type

`$mimeTypes = array("mp4" => "video/mp4");//` --> [See Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694748/mime-type-for-uploaded-files-on-s3) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519393/php-mime-types-list-of-mime-types-publically-available)

```
//get the mime type for file
$type = isset($this->mime_types[$ext]) ? $this->mime_types[$ext] : "application/octet-stream";
```

**Above code works for both url and local files.**

> Note :
>
> Those struggling with CDN mp4 video mime type video/mp4 issue - I had
>   made a change in my class.s3.php file -> in mime_type[] array and also
>   cross checked with putObject() function.
>
> Setting of mime type is always done in coding side and not in AWS S3
>   bucket, We need to use `AWS PHP Class file or sdk` to do the
>   manipulation in mime type or make the necessary changes in core class
>   file (eg. class.s3.php  )

Comment: Ok, and what did u do if the link looks like "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/124070?v=3&s=400" ? There's no any extension in it!

Answer (score 10):

Make use of [`file_info`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) in PHP with `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` flag as the parameter.

[Example taken as it is from PHP Manual]

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
text/html
image/gif
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

---

**`EDIT :`**

You need to enable the extension on your `PHP.ini`

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Remove the semicolon from that line and restart your webserver and you are good to go. 
 [`Installation Doc.`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.setup.php)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :) I have edited the question, I had tried same function and it did not work.I am not sure why !!! no error is coming !!! @Shankar

Comment: @hitesh check which version of PHP do you have

Comment: @hitesh, Did you uncomment the line and then tried restarting ? Also check [**this**](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php)

Comment: @hitesh, You need to ask it as a new question. You just cant go on updating your question like this ... I think this is the 4th time you are updating it.

Answer (score 5):

```
$type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file));
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer but i think http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php [image_type_to_mime_type] and [exif_imagetype][http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php] will only work for images not for other files such as video or document.Do you have any solution for that ?

Comment: hmmm I thought so anyway thanks for the answer !!! it was helpful at least for images :)

Comment: Didn't answer the op's question but you helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

After I tried all these solutions above that's what I use:

`$command = "file -i {$filename}";`

`$mimeTypeArr = shell_exec($command);`

This command returns the line below:

`filename: mime_type`

After I have this I explode and get what I need.

`$mimeTypeArr = shell_exec($command);`

`$mimeTypeArr = explode(':', $mimeTypeArr);`

`$mimeType = trim($mimeTypeArr[1]);`

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can use `file -b -i` to avoid parsing: with `-b` filenames are not prepended to output lines.